# Suppress lint warning about available Support Library preview versions

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I recently updated the Support Library repository on my computer, and it came with version 24.0.0-alpha1 of the Support Library.

Since this is a preview release, I don't want to use that version yet and want to stick with 23.2.1. However, lint now flags all of my support library dependencies as being out of date.

How can I tell lint to ignore alpha and beta versions?

Answer (score 7):

The first step is to create a `lint.xml` file if you do not already have one. This file should be in your modules root, for example at `app/lint.xml`.

You can use this file to customize lint's behavior in a number of ways, such as changing severity levels of specific checks or excluding some checks.

When choosing to ignore a check, you can specify a regular expression that will ignore any warnings with a message that matches the expression.

For an out of date support library version, the message will look something like this:

> A newer version of com.android.support:support-v4 than 23.2.1 is available: 24.0.0-alpha1

Thus the following `lint.xml` file will ignore out of date warnings for any dependency with an available alpha or beta version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lint>
    <!-- Don't warn about available alpha versions -->
    <issue id="GradleDependency">
        <ignore regexp="is available: .*[alpha|beta]" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, got me 99% of the way there for me, but I'd need to make a slight change to the alpha|beta part so the regex took the alpha and beta as whole words, giving me:

`<issue id="GradleDependency">
 <ignore regexp="is available: .*alpha|beta" />
</issue>`

Possibly something changed in the last 5 years, but your answer gets my thumbs up too. :)